# Password login not functioning in MySQL

Tags: mysql, database-administration

I installed MySQL server 8.0 in my ubuntu 20.04 EC2 instance and also did the secure installation using `$ sudo mysql_secure_installation` where I set the password for the root user. I also disabled login into MySQL through anonymous users.

I used `$ sudo mysql -u root -p` to login to MySQL and used the wrong password to confirm whether or not the correct password was enabled and was surprisingly able to login.

Also, I was able to login without the password using just `$ sudo mysql` .

After this I tried to set the password using `ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'PASSWORD';` followed by `FLUSH PRIVILEGES;` in MySQL but got the same results as before.

I also tried modifying the user table directly using `UPDATE mysql.user SET authentication_string=PASSWORD('NEW_USER_PASSWORD') WHERE User='root' AND Host='localhost';` but was met with a syntax error : -

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right s
yntax to use near '('NEW_USER_PASSWORD') WHERE User='root' AND Host='localhost'' at line 1
```

Edit: The mysql.user table before I changed the authentication plugin of root user from `auth_socket` to `caching_sha2_password` .

```
     +-----------+------------------+-----------------------+
     | host      | user             | plugin                |
     +-----------+------------------+-----------------------+
     | localhost | debian-sys-maint | caching_sha2_password |
     | localhost | mysql.infoschema | caching_sha2_password |
     | localhost | mysql.session    | caching_sha2_password |
     | localhost | mysql.sys        | caching_sha2_password |
     | localhost | root             | auth_socket           |
     +-----------+------------------+-----------------------+
```

How can I solve these problems and set my password for the root user?

Comment: About your edit, try this: `UPDATE mysql.user SET plugin = 'mysql_native_password', authentication_string = PASSWORD('your_pass') WHERE User = 'root';`

Comment: Ok. Then, take a look here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-secure-deployment-guide/8.0/en/secure-deployment-configure-authentication.html

Comment: Tried the command but was met with the error: - 
```ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '('your_pass') WHERE User = 'root'' at line 1```

Comment: Ok. Sorry I think PASSWORD() also removed in mysql8
Now if you try this query `SELECT user, plugin FROM mysql.user WHERE user IN ('root');` what is the result ?

Comment: The result is: -
`| root   | auth_socket |` .

I had tried the `UPDATE` command in another EC2 instance where the root user of mysql still has the `auth_socket` plugin, so that I could see if it would change to the `mysql_native_password` plugin. Since the command failed the plugin is the same.

Comment: So try that:
`UPDATE mysql.user SET plugin = 'caching_sha2_password' WHERE user = 'root';
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH caching_sha2_password BY 'your_pass';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;`

Comment: The `UPDATE` command above successfully changed the plugin. On trying to change the password I met with the following error: -
`Your password does not satisfy the current policy requirements` , even with a strong password of length more than 15.

Comment: tell me what is the result of this query: `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'validate_password%';`

Comment: `validate_password.policy` was `MEDIUM`. Changed it to `LOW` using `SET GLOBAL validate_password.policy=LOW;` . After this I was successfully able to set the password.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In MySQL 8.0, `caching_sha2_password`  is the default authentication plugin rather than `mysql_native_password`

You can change root password like bellow:

```
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH caching_sha2_password BY 'your_pass';

-- If first fail because you have changed default authentication plugin you can use mysql_native_password 

ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'your_pass';

FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Comment: I was successful in setting the root user password using the `caching_sha2_password` plugin.

Comment: Changing the authentication plugin from `auth_socket` to `caching_sha2_password` did the trick.

Answer (score -1):

Mysql will permit the (operating system) root user to login without a password based on the principle that if you’re root, you have access to the data anyway. Dont use sudo if you want to test a non-root user login.

Comment: Have a look here : https://websiteforstudents.com/mysql-server-installed-without-password-for-root-on-ubuntu-17-10-18-04/ - you’ll see that if you’re the o/s root user you do _not_ need a password to login as root to the db.

Comment: You can change the default authentication method (as that article describes if needed - but the answer stands - you’ll see the OP uses ‘sudo mysql’ which effectively makes him(or her) root.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and the reference site @FreudianSlip. Both precisely describe the issue I was facing with password authentication in MySQL. I used the `caching_sha2_password` plugin instead of the `mysql_native_password` plugin since it was the default authentication plugin for MySQL 8.0, which I was using.

Comment: Also, I noticed that just `$ sudo mysql` doesn't work anymore, I have to login using '$ sudo mysql -u root -p' and then typing the password. So I guess the OS root user doesn't have direct access to mysql without the `unix_socket` plugin.